# How to Make Customized Dropdown list with background color and small dropdown image at right side?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Am developing small project in which i got stuck up, where drop-down list's background is not able to change it's default color. i want to make customized drop-down list by color and small image at right side using jquery mobile 1.4.5 . please guide me/help me out

```
<div class="Own-card-payment"> 
      <select id="selectCardVals" data-native-menu="false" ></select>
     <select name="dropdown" id="selectCreditCardNums" data-native-menu="false">     </select> 
</div>
```

Thank you in advance
Aniruddh

Comment: We need to have a look at your code.

Comment: this code i had used ...<div class="Own-card-payment">
   <select id="selectCardVals" data-native-menu="false" ></select>
   <select name="dropdown" id="selectCreditCardNums"  data-native-menu="false"></select>


  </div>

Comment: i guess jqm.css is override ! is there anyway how to overcome this ?

Comment: You should provide small portion of your code. Where it involve the problem, what library are you using, and other information. Use four space or backtick to create a code `like this`. Anyway, you could edit your main post. Don't put your code in comment like that.

Comment: I am new user to stackoverflow !

Comment: am using cordova 3.6.4 library jqm 1.4.5 version

Answer (score 0):

Just add some CSS styles to change the colours. Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/umkta1La/)

```
#selectCardVals {
    background-color: #000;
}
#selectCreditCardNums {
    background-color: #0912FF; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set data-menu-native="false", jQM creates a popup or dialog with the options, so your CSS needs to target that created element rather than the select element. Depending how many options are in the SELECT and the height of your page, either a popup or a dialog will be displayed.

The created popup has the ID of the select plus "-listbox" or plus "-dialog", and the listitem anchors have the background color, therefore your CSS should look something like this:

```
#selectCardVals-listbox a, #selectCardVals-dialog a {
    background-color: #e29b2c;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: white;
}
#selectCreditCardNums-listbox a, #selectCreditCardNums-dialog a {
    background-color: #024DAC;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: white;
}
```

To add an image at the top right of the popup, you could do something like this:

```
#selectCardVals-listbox{
    padding-top: 40px;
    background-color: #e29b2c;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/40/40/technics/1/);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-position: top right;
}
#selectCardVals-dialog .ui-header{
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/40/40/technics/2/);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-position: top right;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/umkta1La/3/)**